# Install a third party without package.swift with the Swift package manager

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I was installing **AmazonS3RequestManager** in my iOS App project through the Swift package manager. But was unable to install because it hasn't package.swift file.

Is there any way to install the third party library which does not have a Package.swift file using SPM?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way.

It's not only the missing package.swift file, the folder structure must match the requirements.